# Random Array Picker - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i was coding for a small project but my random array picker doesnt work

```
var btnarray = [xfn.left, xn.left, xnln.left, xln.left, xnn.left];
```

(this is the array)

```
var rand = btnarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
```

(this is the random picker var)

Well, when i start, the rand value results equal to btnarray[0]

anyone can help me please?

Oh i perfectly know that the variables are all different.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: the code works as expected the only thing ou need to change is to use the array length in your random ```btnarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * btnarray.length)];```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Instead of posting 2 lines from your code, put it in a bit of context: are these lines both in a function, one right after the other?

Comment: the rand var is equal every time to xfn.left.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array's length is 5, you need to multiply the value of the random function by that number. Better yet, use the `length` property.

```
var rand = btnarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * btnarray.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `Math.floor` since it will make very hard to get the last element in your `btnarray` array, you'll need to get **exactly** the number `btnarray.length` in order to get at that element. Also, `floor` tends to *flatten* probability outcomes and looks like you're *stuck* on some value(s) since it's threshold is forcing you to have the greatest integer smaller than or equal to some number.

You should use `round` instead, this will even the probability  for every array element and will give you more *apparently* random indexes. Try this, it's already tested with a dummy `btnarray` array variable and works fine.

```
var rand = btnarray[Math.round(Math.random() * btnarray.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you toss this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

you can just do this:

```
var randomValue = rando(btnarray).value
```

I usually go with [randojs.com](https://randojs.com/) because it can handle pretty much any random functionality you need, and it's all short and easy to read.